# Words to describe closer or farther from "waist" or traverse plane?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are words like proximal and distal that can be used to describe an object (part) with respect to its distance from the body's vertical centerline. Is there something similar that can be used to described the relative distance from the *waistline*?

i.e. You can't use "upper" or "lower" because they're absolute. I am looking for something more like "inner/outer" or "proximal/distal".

The best I can describe is earth - "equatorial" would be centerline - "tropical" could be close to the equator, "arctic" would be towards the poles. The importance being, "tropical" and "arctic" (zones) would describe those both north and south of the equator.

[image]

The two "arctic" rings are the same, as are the two "tropical" ones. i.e. I want names that identify each, and indicate their appropriate allowable positions.

For example, I am looking for words that mean "closer to the poles" vs. "farther from the poles".

Comment: 'Central' and 'peripheral' are hypernyms (close to or distant from a centre).

Comment: You can't use geographical terms and bodily terms and expect to come out winning. That said, x inches or millimeters above/below the waistline. X miles or kilometers above/below the equator. North or south of the equator is a **latitude**. https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/latitude

Comment: I think there may not be a word for this, simply because it's not something that physiologists need to refer to. The centerline of the body has some special significance due to development, but there isn't as much significance to the waist.

Comment: If you're looking for a word applicable generally (eg to a sphere to describe the relative position of your tropical and arctic layers) you may have confused matters by referring to "the body". If you're actually looking for terms used in the context of the human body, you're probably out of luck. But the mixing of words used and images used in your question is a bit confusing.